# After opening multiple web pages many times, freezing often occurs

Tags: cefsharp

I am developing a web crawler that will frequently request new web pages. During the testing process, the program often freezes.

I've written a test case that explains my usage and the scenario where the problem has occurred.

Sometimes, when it open a web page for 10 times, it may get stuck when it open it for 20 times. How many times do it open the web page, i are not sure.

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        System.Timers.Timer timer;
        int i = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(400) { AutoReset = true };//Timer, automatically open a new web page
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.baidu.com") { Parent = splitContainer1.Panel1, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler(splitContainer1.Panel2);
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;
        }

        private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain == false) return;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            i = i > 1 ? 1 : i + 1;
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('mnav c-font-normal c-color-t')[" + (i) + "].click()");//Open a link in the web page
        }
    }


    class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
    {
        Control host;

        internal LifeSpanHandler(Control host)
        {
            this.host = host;
        }

        public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {

        }

        public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {

        }

        public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
        {
            newBrowser = null;

            var webBrowser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)chromiumWebBrowser;
            webBrowser.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (host.HasChildren) host.Controls[0].Dispose();
                var control = new Control { Parent = host, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
                control.CreateControl();
                windowInfo.SetAsChild(control.Handle);
            }));

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The test code is placed on GitHub, which is the visual studio 2019 project. We hope you can execute the project locally, so as to find problems more intuitively. Thank you very much.

https://github.com/haohaodz/cefsharp-form-vs2019-problem.git

Comment: What does `Sometimes, when it open a web page for 10 times, it may get stuck when it open it for 20 times` mean exactly?

Comment: `What does  (Sometimes, when it open a web page for 10 times, it may get stuck when it open it for 20 times)   mean exactly?` Sorry, I mean the number of pages opened is uncertain when the program freezes. Sometimes, when it have opened 10 web pages, it will freezes. Sometimes, it will freezes after it have opened 20 pages. In short, the program repeatedly open the web page, there will be a high probability of deadlock.

Comment: you can download https://github.com/haohaodz/cefsharp-form-vs2019-problem/archive/master.zip  ,The code is vs2019 project.Thank you very much.

Comment: How does it behave it you comment out the timer and performance the link clicks manually?

Comment: Maybe it's a newline problem. The actual code is not commented out. The page is automatically clicked through the timer. I have also tried to manually click the links frequently, and the program freezes too.

Comment: I didn't say it was, I suggested you test without the timer.

Comment: Is DoClose called when you dispose of the container control?

Comment: I'd also suggest testing without assigning your Lifespan handler.

Comment: `I didn't say it was, I suggested you test without the timer.`   Manual click many times will still be dead without the timer.

Comment: `Is DoClose called when you dispose of the container control?`  DoClose Is not  called

Comment: `I'd also suggest testing without assigning your Lifespan handler.`  Manual click many times will still be dead without my Lifespan handler.

Comment: Have you tested with other websites?  Does the problem reproduce with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: `Have you tested with other websites? Does the problem reproduce with github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample`
  please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447414/13973332

Answer (score -1):

> Have you tested with other websites?

High frequency of requests to other websites can also lead to deadlock.

> Does the problem reproduce with github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

the problem does not reproduce with github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample.

in BrowserTabUserControl.cs

```
browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler(openPopupsAsTabs: false);
```

It opens a web page in a new window by default.High frequency of open multiple web pages, the freezing problem does not reproduce.

I change openPopupsAsTabs to true and open a new page in tabs

```
browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler(openPopupsAsTabs: true);
```

High frequency of open multiple web pages, the program will freezes.
The program freezes in the dispose method:

```
System.Windows.Forms .dll! System.Windows.Forms . UnsafeNativeMethods.DestroyWindow ( 
     System.Runtime.InteropServices . handleref hWnd) unknown
System.Windows.Forms .dll! System.Windows.Forms . NativeWindow.DestroyHandle () unknown
System.Windows.Forms .dll! System.Windows.Forms . Control.DestroyHandle () unknown
System.Windows.Forms .dll! System.Windows.Forms . Control.Dispose (bool disposing) unknown
System.dll ! System.ComponentModel.Component . dispose() unknown
```

Sometimes the program exits suddenly,There is an exception:

```
Exception thrown:“ System.IO.PipeException ”(located at System.ServiceModel.dll (2)
Exception thrown:“ System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ”(located at System.ServiceModel.dll (2)
Exception thrown:“ System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ”(located at System.ServiceModel.dll (2)
Exception thrown:“ System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ”(located at System.ServiceModel.dll (2)
Exception thrown:“ System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ”(located at System.ServiceModel.Internals . DLL)
Exception thrown:“ System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ”(located at System.ServiceModel.Internals . DLL)
Exception thrown:“ System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException ”(located at System.ServiceModel.dll (2)
```